# Images, fonts and looks in IE are not as in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using bootstrap CSS in rails app. Images are displayed with right sizes(configured in CSS or code) but in IE They are displayed in original size.

Tested on IE8
Bootstrap version - 2.3

**Shim:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toptext3 pull-left">
      Designed By 
      <%=link_to "Exaltech Solutions Pvt. Ltd.", "http://www.exaltech.co.in" , target: "_blank"%>
     </div>
     <div class="toptext2 pull-right">
       Follow Us on:
       <%= link_to image_tag("Facebook.png", size:'30x30'),"https://www.facebook.com/computerzcom", target: "_blank" %>
       <%= link_to image_tag("Twitter.png", size:'30x30'), "https://twitter.com/computerzcom", target: "_blank" %>
       <%= link_to image_tag("ebay.png", size: '30x60'), "http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/computerzhh/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_from=&_ipg=&_trksid=p3686", target: "_blank" %>&nbsp;
       <dfn><a href="#myModal"  data-toggle="modal">Testimonial</a></dfn>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <dfn><a href="#myModal2"  data-toggle="modal">Terms</a></dfn>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       Computerz.com &#169; 2013
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have anything relevant in CSS related to this part and it is too long so I am not putting it over here. In this ebay icon is coming huge(of its original size) instead of small icon.

Apologies for not adding code before. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Could you provide some code perhaps?

Comment: You really need to provide yout html/css. Are you specifying a valid doctype? And if it's an html5 doctype are you including the html5 shim?

Comment: For HTML and CSS, you need to provide sample code.

Comment: Which version of IE, which version of bootstrap, example code?

Comment: Although I got a workaround but I am keen to know real solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had many images which were distorted and were displayed in original size in IE instead of size which I gave in ruby code.

Workaround - I resized all images to sizes they were needed in photoshop and then used them as assets.